# In Selenium how does ChromeDriver executable finds Chrome browser?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

For Selenium, we define the chrome executable path in System.setProperty. When a URL is passed in driver.get and Chrome invokes:

1 - How does chrome executable know where Chrome browser is actually installed?

2 - What would happen if I do not have Chrome browser?

Responses appreciated!!

Comment: Start reading the [Getting started section](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [**Requirements**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver#requirements) of **ChromeDriver**:

> The **ChromeDriver** consists of three separate pieces. There is the browser itself i.e. **chrome**, the language bindings provided by the Selenium project i.e. the **driver** and an executable downloaded from the Chromium project which acts as a bridge between **chrome** and the **driver**. This executable is called the **chromedriver**, we generally refer to it as the **server** to reduce confusion.

The server expects you to have Chrome installed in the *default location* for each system as per the image below:

[image: Chrome_binary_expected_location]

<sup>1</sup>For Linux systems, the ChromeDriver expects `/usr/bin/google-chrome` to be a symlink to the actual Chrome binary. In case you are using a **Chrome** executable in a non-standard location you have to *override the Chrome binary location.* as follows:

[image: Chrome executable in a non-standard location]

Comment: The question is how selenium finds the path to Chrome browser without setting the binary? I looked at Python selenium source, there it can find Firefox executable by searching windows registry. I couldn't find any Chromium location detection in the source so far.

Comment: And Chrome location on my computer is `C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe` as opposed to your screenshot.

Comment: I have the same question as @Max ever figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

Google chrome doesn't have built-in driver server, so you need to install ChromeDriver so **that the selenium code communicates with the chrome browser**.This ChromeDriver implements webdriver's wire protocol (client being system on which webdriver API is used & server being browser acting as/containing stand alone server).
For Internet explorer one needs to install InternetExplorerDriver as stand alone server. For Selenium 3.0 & above to work with firefox, Geckodrver has to be installed.

Comment: This is ok, I get it. My question was how does the ChromeDriver executable (or Gecko or IE) actually "start" the Chrome browser? The driver executable is in some location (say D:\Software) and Chrome can be some random location chosen by user (not C:\program files always)